# Searching all users' emails in office 365 for items sent to certain people

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When someone views contact details in our CRM, I would like to pull in a summary of recent correspondence.

I can search one user easily enough:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jo@example.com/messages?$search="bob@example.com"&$select=from,sender,toRecipients,subject
```

But you have to cross reference every user with every contact is a lot of requests.

Is it possible to search the Microsoft Graph for all emails sent from/to an address from/to all users?

If not, is there any other API / Tech out there that could get me the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to search across mailboxes from Microsoft Graph API.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.